# Javascript at form submit does not run

Tags: php, javascript

i'm trying to make a form for my website, to transfer some data easily.
I am trying to call in a small javascript when the form submits, but it doesn't run.

below this you can see the PhP function in wich i make my form (in a small table)
and below that i'll enter my javascript.

Any help on this matter would be useful

thanks in advance

php:

```
function addrow($itemText , $itemPrice , $itemID , $odd)
{
     if ($odd)
     {
            echo "<tr class=\"content-row online\" id=\"958\" bgcolor=#A7A7A7>";
     }
     else
     {
            echo "<tr class=\"content-row online\" id=\"958\" bgcolor=#BFBFBF>";
     }
     echo "<td style=\"width: 70%;\">$itemText</td>";
     echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>$itemPrice</b></td>";
     if (hasRole($itemID))
     {
          echo "<td style=\"width: 15%; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Unlocked</b></td>";
     }
     else
     {
          echo "<td style=\"width: 15%; padding-left: 5px;\"><b><form name=\"buy\" action=\"php-scripts/BuyItem.php\" onsubmit=\"return buyItem($itemPrice)\" >";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"UserID\" value =\"".getUID()."\">";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"itemID\" value = \"".$itemID."\" >";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"reqKarma\" value = \"".$itemPrice."\" >";
          echo "<input name=\"Send\" type=\"submit\" value=\"       Buy Now       \" /></form></b></td>";
     }     
     echo "</tr>";
}
```

javascript:

```
function buyItem(reqKarma)
{
       var currKarma = <?php getKarma(); ?>;
       alert(currKarma +"");
       if (currKarma < reqKarma)
       {
            alert('You do not have enough Karma to buy this title.');
            return false;
       }
}
```

Full document:

```
<?php
include "php-scripts/DBConnection.php";
$con = getconnection();
mysql_select_db("brokendi_BD", $con);
loadpage();

function loadpage()
{
      echo "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"width: 98%\" >";
      echo "<tr class=\"info-row\" bgcolor=#252525 style=\"color:white;  height: 15px;\">";
      echo "<td style=\"width: 70%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Item Name</b></td>";
      echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Item Price</b></td>";
      echo "<td style=\"width: 15%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b> </b></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      addrow("test",1,1,false);
      echo "</table>";
}

function addrow($itemText , $itemPrice , $itemID , $odd)
{
     if ($odd)
     {
            echo "<tr class=\"content-row online\" id=\"958\" bgcolor=#A7A7A7>";
     }
     else
     {
            echo "<tr class=\"content-row online\" id=\"958\" bgcolor=#BFBFBF>";
     }
     echo "<td style=\"width: 70%;\">$itemText</td>";
     echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>$itemPrice</b></td>";
     if (hasRole($itemID))
     {
          echo "<td style=\"width: 15%; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Unlocked</b></td>";
     }
     else
     {
          echo "<td style=\"width: 15%; padding-left: 5px;\"><b><form name=\"buy\" action=\"php-scripts/BuyItem.php\" onsubmit=\"return buyItem($itemPrice)\" >";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"UserID\" value =\"".getUID()."\">";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"itemID\" value = \"".$itemID."\" >";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"reqKarma\" value = \"".$itemPrice."\" >";
          echo "<input name=\"Send\" type=\"submit\" value=\"       Buy Now       \" /></form></b></td>";
     }     
     echo "</tr>";
}


function getKarma()
{
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userpoints WHERE uid='getUID()'");
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
       $currentkarma = (int)$row['points'];

      return $currentkarma;
}

function getUID()
{
     global $user;
     if ($user->uid) 
     { 
          $userID=$user->uid;
          return $userID;
     }
     else
    {
          header('Location: http://brokendiamond.org/?q=node/40');
    }
}

function hasRole($roleID)
{
       $usersid = getUID();
       $returnValue = false;
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_roles");
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      { 
           if ($row['uid'] == $usersid)
           {
                  if ($row['rid'] == $roleID)
                  {
                          $returnValue = true;
                          break;
                  }
           }
      }
      return $returnValue;
}

function enoughKarma($requiredKarma)
{
        if ( getKarma() >= $requiredKarma)
        {
                 return true;
        }
        else
        {
                return false;
        }      
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function buyItem(reqKarma)
{
       var currKarma = <?php getKarma(); ?>;
       alert(currKarma +"");
       if (currKarma < reqKarma)
       {
            alert('You do not have enough Karma to buy this title.');
            return false;
       }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return true;` from the `buyItem` function if you wan't the form to submit. You return false without enough karma, but nothing with enough, which means the function returns `undefined` and that prevents the form from submitting.

Try:

```
function buyItem(reqKarma)
{
    var currKarma = <?php getKarma(); ?>;
    alert(currKarma +"");
    if (currKarma < reqKarma)
    {
         alert('You do not have enough Karma to buy this title.');
         return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Depending on what the function actually does, you may need to change `<?php getKarma(); ?>` to `<?php echo getKarma(); ?>`.

Comment: getKarma returns a value, and the form can not be submitted when you don't have enough karma,

Comment: i added the full document, so you can see the other functions

Comment: Given the extra code you posted, you need to change `var currKarma = <?php getKarma(); ?>;` to `var currKarma = <?php echo getKarma(); ?>;`  Also make sure to add return true to the end of buyItem.  Also make sure to check those same values on the server side because a user can easily spoof their karma on the client side or bypass that validation and submit the form regardless of karma.

Comment: its fixed, i changed that line and its completely fixed

Answer (score 2):

It's really not a good idea to write full HTML in PHP, it's just messy.

Change:

```
echo "<td style=\"width: 15%; padding-left: 5px;\"><b><form name=\"buy\" action=\"php-scripts/BuyItem.php\" onsubmit=\"return buyItem($itemPrice)\" >";
```

to:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function buyItem<?php echo $itemID;?> {
    buyItem(<?php echo json_encode($itemPrice);?>);
}
</script>
<td style="width: 15%; padding-left: 5px;"><b><form name="buy" action="php-scripts/BuyItem.php" onsubmit="return buyItem<?php echo $itemID;?>()">
<?php
```

I've done two things here:

1. Removed HTML from PHP code.
2. Added a `json_encode` to values being passed to JavaScript. This may seem trivial, but for more complex data `json_encode` is a real life saver.

The reason your script is broken is probable because of a syntax error occurring in your JavaScript.

What does `<?php getKarma(); ?>` do?

Comment: it gives a value back, ( the on site currency )

Comment: i added the full document, ;)